# How can I get xrandr to detect both nvidia cards: 2 x GTX480, triple-head?

Tags: xorg, x11, drivers, nvidia, multi-monitor

- I am running Linux Mint 16 (Petra)
- I am running the default driver nvidia-319 shipped with the distro
- I have 2x GTX480 cards
- I have 3 monitors
- Using the Nvidia driver, all monitors and GPUs are picked up by the proprietary utility.

However, similarly to the report at https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/719768/linux/304-121-ubuntu-14-04-xrandr-1-4-multi-gpu-not-being-detected/ when I run xrandr --listproviders I am only shown a single provider -- the first card. I have xrandr 1.4, so should be able to see both. If I set up a separate X screen and then do xrandr --listproviders --screen 1, I can see the second card. However, I do not want multiple X screens; I want to be able to seamlessly flow between monitors.

I do not want to run xinerama as it is a pain in the neck to setup and should be superseded by xrandr.

Using the nouveau driver I can use all three screens exactly as I would like, but the performance is not good.

So, I have a few questions:

1.) Is this behaviour by design or a bug? I note at http://uk.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.12/README/randr14.html that the driver only supports the Source Output capability; would that stop me just seeing two different card providers in xrandr?

2.) If the former is true, is there a way that I can work around this?

3.) I've played around with various basemosaic options, to no avail

The last configuration I tried was:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247"
    HorizSync       24.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics W2243"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: unknown, VertRefresh source: unknown
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "AOC LM720/LM720A"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 480"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 480"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 480"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"       
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "True"
    Option         "MetaModes" "GPU-1.CRT-0: 1280x1024+0+0, GPU-0.CRT-0: 1920x1080+1280+0, GPU-0.DFP-2: 1920x1080+3200+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"       
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "True"
    Option         "MetaModes" "GPU-1.CRT-0: 1280x1024+0+0, GPU-0.CRT-0: 1920x1080+1280+0, GPU-0.DFP-2: 1920x1080+3200+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"       
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "True"
    Option         "MetaModes" "GPU-1.CRT-0: 1280x1024+0+0, GPU-0.CRT-0: 1920x1080+1280+0, GPU-0.DFP-2: 1920x1080+3200+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The X log when running with no config is:

```
[     6.896] 
X.Org X Server 1.14.5
Release Date: 2013-12-12
[     6.896] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     6.896] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     6.896] Current Operating System: Linux theoria 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64
[     6.896] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic root=UUID=3a6b3275-5e15-40c7-8de6-9eea1c63ebe1 ro quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax
[     6.896] Build Date: 17 December 2013  10:06:15AM
[     6.896] xorg-server 2:1.14.5-1ubuntu2~saucy1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[     6.896] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[     6.896]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     6.896] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     6.896] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Apr  9 07:12:33 2014
[     6.897] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     6.897] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     6.897] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     6.897] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     6.897] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     6.898] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     6.899] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[     6.899] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     6.899] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     6.899] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fe4b0739d20
[     6.899] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     6.899]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     6.899]    X.Org Video Driver: 14.1
[     6.899]    X.Org XInput driver : 19.1
[     6.899]    X.Org Server Extension : 7.0
[     6.900] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     6.900] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[     6.901] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:06c0:10de:075f rev 163, Mem @ 0xf4000000/33554432, 0xe0000000/134217728, 0xe8000000/67108864, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[     6.901] (--) PCI: (0:2:0:0) 10de:06c0:10de:075f rev 163, Mem @ 0xf0000000/33554432, 0xd0000000/134217728, 0xd8000000/67108864, I/O @ 0x0000d000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[     6.901] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[     6.901] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[     6.901] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[     6.901] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[     6.901] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     6.901] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[     6.901] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[     6.903] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[     6.964] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.964]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 0.5.1
[     6.964]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     6.964] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     6.964] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[     6.993] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     6.993]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     6.993]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     6.993] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  319.60  Wed Sep 25 14:24:11 PDT 2013
[     6.993] Loading extension GLX
[     6.993] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[     6.993] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[     6.993] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 2
[     6.993] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 3
[     6.993] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 4
[     6.993] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 5
[     6.993] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[     6.993] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 7
[     6.993] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 8
[     6.993] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     6.993] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     6.994] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[     7.001] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     7.001]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.001]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     7.002] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[     7.002] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[     7.004] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.004]    compiled for 1.14.2.901, module version = 1.0.9
[     7.004]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     7.004]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[     7.004] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     7.004] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     7.005] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.005]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 2.3.2
[     7.005]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     7.005]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[     7.005] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     7.005] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     7.006] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.006]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.8.0
[     7.006]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     7.006]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[     7.006] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     7.006] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     7.007] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.007]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.4.3
[     7.007]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     7.007]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[     7.007] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  319.60  Wed Sep 25 14:04:14 PDT 2013
[     7.007] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[     7.007] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Wed Jul 31 10:51:03 2013 +1000
[     7.007] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[     7.007]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[     7.007]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[     7.007]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[     7.007]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[     7.007]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[     7.007]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[     7.007]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[     7.007]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[     7.008]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[     7.008]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[     7.008]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[     7.008]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[     7.008]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[     7.008] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     7.008] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     7.008] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     7.008] (++) using VT number 7

[     7.021] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     7.021] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     7.021] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     7.022] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.022]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.022]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     7.022] (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey
[     7.022] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[     7.022] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[     7.022] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[     7.024] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.024]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.024]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     7.024] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[     7.024] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[     7.024] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[     7.025] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.025]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 1.1.0
[     7.025]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     7.025] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[     7.025] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[     7.025] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[     7.026] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
[     7.026] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[     7.026] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     7.026] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     7.026] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     7.026] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     7.026] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     7.027] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.027]    compiled for 1.14.5, module version = 0.0.2
[     7.027]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[     7.027] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[     7.027] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     7.027] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[     7.027] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[     7.027] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     7.027] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     7.027] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[     7.627] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[     7.627] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[     7.656] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2)) does not
[     7.656] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     support NVIDIA 3D Vision stereo.
[     7.657] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 480 (GF100) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[     7.657] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1572864 kBytes
[     7.657] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 70.00.21.00.02
[     7.657] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce GTX 480 at PCI:1:0:0
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0):     LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0) (boot, connected)
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-1
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0):     Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2) (connected)
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0): LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: Internal Single Link TMDS
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-1: Internal Single Link TMDS
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0): Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.659] (--) NVIDIA(0): Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2): Internal Dual Link TMDS
[     7.659] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[     7.659] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0) (Using EDID
[     7.659] (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
[     7.659] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[     7.660] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2) (Using
[     7.660] (**) NVIDIA(0):     EDID frequencies has been enabled on all display
[     7.660] (**) NVIDIA(0):     devices.)
[     7.661] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[     7.661] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[     7.661] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[     7.661] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[     7.661] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[     7.661] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select{},DFP-2:nvidia-auto-select{}"
[     7.661] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 3840 x 1080
[     7.681] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (101, 101); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[     7.681] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[     7.681] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     7.681] (II) Unloading vesa
[     7.681] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[     7.681] (II) Unloading fbdev
[     7.681] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[     7.681] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[     7.681] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[     8.500] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Found DRM driver nvidia-drm (20130102)
[     8.571] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Display (AOC LM720/LM720A (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[     8.571] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-1):     Vision stereo.
[     8.575] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-1): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 480 (GF100) at PCI:2:0:0 (GPU-1)
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Memory: 1572864 kBytes
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): VideoBIOS: 70.00.21.00.02
[     8.575] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Valid display device(s) on GeForce GTX 480 at PCI:2:0:0
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1):     AOC LM720/LM720A (CRT-0) (boot, connected)
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1):     CRT-1
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1):     DFP-0
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1):     DFP-1
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1):     DFP-2
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): AOC LM720/LM720A (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-0: Internal Single Link TMDS
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-1: Internal Single Link TMDS
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-2: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     8.575] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-2: Internal Single Link TMDS
[     8.575] (II) NVIDIA: Using 3072.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[     8.575] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[     8.579] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select{},DFP-2:nvidia-auto-select{}"
[     8.662] Loading extension NV-GLX
[     8.755] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[     8.755] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[     8.755] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[     8.755] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[     8.756] Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[     8.756] Loading extension XINERAMA
[     8.756] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[     8.756] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     8.756] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[     8.756] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[     8.756] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[     8.756] (--) RandR disabled
[     8.759] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[     8.759] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[     8.771] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[     8.776] (II) config/udev: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     8.776] (II) config/udev: Ignoring already known drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   666.012] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[   666.012] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[   666.012] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   666.012] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0) (Using EDID
[   666.012] (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
[   666.043] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2)) does not
[   666.043] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     support NVIDIA 3D Vision stereo.
[   666.043] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   666.043] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2) (Using
[   666.043] (**) NVIDIA(0):     EDID frequencies has been enabled on all display
[   666.043] (**) NVIDIA(0):     devices.)
[   666.204] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DVI-I-3: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[   666.236] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DVI-I-3: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[   666.345] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[   666.345] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[   666.345] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   666.345] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0) (Using EDID
[   666.345] (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
[   666.376] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2)) does not
[   666.376] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     support NVIDIA 3D Vision stereo.
[   666.376] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   666.376] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2) (Using
[   666.376] (**) NVIDIA(0):     EDID frequencies has been enabled on all display
[   666.376] (**) NVIDIA(0):     devices.)
[   667.413] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[   667.413] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[   667.413] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   667.413] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0) (Using EDID
[   667.413] (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
[   667.444] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2)) does not
[   667.444] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     support NVIDIA 3D Vision stereo.
[   667.444] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   667.444] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2) (Using
[   667.444] (**) NVIDIA(0):     EDID frequencies has been enabled on all display
[   667.444] (**) NVIDIA(0):     devices.)
[   667.560] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7996F6726817F73651B9DE0FDA11E35FC4524568.xkm
[   667.568] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-14B7503D830F6433941F279130885A2D664E08AA.xkm
[   668.724] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-14B7503D830F6433941F279130885A2D664E08AA.xkm
[   668.727] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-14B7503D830F6433941F279130885A2D664E08AA.xkm
[   668.730] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-14B7503D830F6433941F279130885A2D664E08AA.xkm
[   668.733] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-14B7503D830F6433941F279130885A2D664E08AA.xkm
[   668.736] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-14B7503D830F6433941F279130885A2D664E08AA.xkm
[   668.739] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-14B7503D830F6433941F279130885A2D664E08AA.xkm
[   668.742] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-14B7503D830F6433941F279130885A2D664E08AA.xkm
[   687.505] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[   687.505] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[   687.505] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   687.505] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LG Electronics W2243 (CRT-0) (Using EDID
[   687.505] (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
[   687.536] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2)) does not
[   687.536] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     support NVIDIA 3D Vision stereo.
[   687.536] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   687.536] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247 (DFP-2) (Using
[   687.536] (**) NVIDIA(0):     EDID frequencies has been enabled on all display
[   687.536] (**) NVIDIA(0):     devices.)
[  1212.601] (II) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Close
[  1212.601] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  1212.601] (II) evdev: USB USB Keykoard: Close
[  1212.601] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  1212.601] (II) evdev: USB USB Keykoard: Close
[  1212.601] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  1212.601] (II) evdev: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM): Close
[  1212.601] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  1212.601] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[  1212.601] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  1212.601] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[  1212.601] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  1212.860] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I've snipped some of the  log to keep to the character count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin-
Very similar setup on my end, except with a pair of nvidia GT9800's - circa 2008!. Also an onboard Intel HD4000 (disabled in bios). xrandr only showed 1 gpu, though all other sys related tools properly reported both. ubuntu 14.04 lts beta 2, nvidia 331.28 proprietary

The holy grail fix for me last night was: Base Mosaic! Empty xorg.conf, nvidia x server settings-> Enable Base Mosaic, then enable each detected display. It all just works! fast seemless multi-gpu, multi-head multi-monitor setup with 1 xscreen! My 3 displays are different resolutions and one is rotated portrait. Even the ubuntu Settings - Displays correctly shows all 3 monitors.

I suggest upgrading to the nvidia 331.28 proprietary drivers, blow out your xorg.conf, and try base Mosaic again.

-chad

➜  ~  nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info

```
Number of GPUs: 2
GPU #0:
  Name      : GeForce 9800 GT
  UUID      : GPU-56281125-01c7-ee85-b8b9-b3e5cf94b7c5
  PCI BusID : PCI:1:0:0
  Number of Display Devices: 1
  Display Device 0 (CRT-0):
      EDID Name             : Samsung SyncMaster
      Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 81.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 56 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 75 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 146.250 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1680 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1050 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1680 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1050 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 470 mm
      Physical Height       : 300 mm
GPU #1:
  Name      : GeForce 9800 GT
  UUID      : GPU-cbc59e3f-e8c1-a347-a069-b62f6b885f7d
  PCI BusID : PCI:2:0:0
  Number of Display Devices: 2
  Display Device 0 (CRT-0):
      EDID Name             : Samsung SyncMaster
      Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 81.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 56 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 75 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 140.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1280 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1024 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1440 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 900 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 410 mm
      Physical Height       : 270 mm

  Display Device 1 (DFP-1):
      EDID Name             : Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VH242H
      Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 85.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 55 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 75 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 160.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1080 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1080 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 520 mm
      Physical Height       : 290 mm
```

Below is my xorg.conf - All of which x server settings generated. Note that it is quite straight forward, and does not even reference my second GPU.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9800 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

auto-select +3600+0 {rotation=right}, GPU-cbc59e3f-e8c1-a347-a069-b62f6b885f7d.GPU-1.DVI-I-3: nvidia-auto-select +1680+180"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "GPU-56281125-01c7-ee85-b8b9-b3e5cf94b7c5.GPU-0.DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+180, GPU-cbc59e3f-e8c1-a347-a069-b62f6b885f7d.GPU-1.DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select +3600+0 {rotation=right}, GPU-cbc59e3f-e8c1-a347-a069-b62f6b885f7d.GPU-1.DVI-I-3: nvidia-auto-select +1680+180"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "SLI" "off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "on"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Hmm. Getting closer. Thanks for the help! I implemented a similar solution but now:

[   209.366] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to find a valid Base Mosaic configuration.
[   209.366] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Invalid Base Mosaic configuration 1 of 1:
[   209.366] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): GPUs:
[   209.366] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     1) NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0
[   209.366] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     2) NVIDIA GPU at PCI:2:0:0
[   209.366] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Errors:
[   209.366] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     - The video link was not detected
[   209.366] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     - Trouble accessing PCI Config Space

Comment: Did you install the SLI bridge (hardware)?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @chadical. I played around a bit more and here's what finally worked: https://www.martineve.com/2014/04/15/enabling-a-triple-head-3-monitor-setup-on-linux-mint-16-petra-with-two-nvidia-cards/ (you may want to update your answer but I will award bounty as it's now working!)

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me a lot, but there were a lot more steps than what's described in the answer so I thought I'd leave a comment with the details steps that worked for me.

1. Use the “Driver Manger” app in “System Settings” to select “nvidia-346” as the driver (not “nvidia-346-updates”). Click “Apply Changes”. Once the application is done processing nothing will happen (nothing will get installed, no prompt will appear, no message will be shown). Restart your computer (this is needed because NVIDIA's driver modify the kernel apparently and only a full system restart will cause the install to go through).
2. When Linux Mint launches after the restart, Cinnamon will be broken and only 2 of your monitors will work. Do not bother trying to fix Cinnamon this will just lead you down a path of useless installs.
3. Launch the “Terminal” app. This will be tricky when Cinnamon is broken because “Terminal” is mysteriously missing from the Applications list in the task bar! And right-clicking on the Desktop is also broken. The only way I've found to launch it is to use the shortcut created in Step 1 or use the keyboard shortcut Alt + F2. When a window pops up asking you to type a command to run - use "sudo ls" and check the "Use Terminal" checkbox. When a terminal launches, use the Ctrl+Shift+T keyboard shortcut to open a fresh terminal tab. Now you can close the original tab which is waiting for your sudo password. (You'll need to do this any time you want to launch a new terminal window).
4. In the terminal, run these commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers 
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-settings
   sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
5. Reboot your computer. There is no UI button to do this so you'll need to run `sudo reboot`.
6. When the computer reboots things will still be broken. I'm not sure about steps 7 and 8. They may not be needed, but I did this while trying to figure out what's wrong so including them here just in case.
7. Next, run `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. In the editor, find the line that defines `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and change it to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
   ```
8. Now, in Terminal run this:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   sudo update-grub2
   sudo update-grub
   ```
9. Now use `sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` to edit you X Config file. This step sucks because there's no nice GUI for editing this config file and if you make a mistake and corrupt this file - next time you reboot - you'll have no GUI anymore and possibly not even a working console. Make a back up of this file first. Once backed up, you'll want generally follow the things outlined here: https://www.martineve.com/2014/04/15/enabling-a-triple-head-3-monitor-setup-on-linux-mint-16-petra-with-two-nvidia-cards/ For me the changes I made were:

   - Make sure the "ServerLayout" section only defines Screen 0. There should be no lines defining "Screen 1". If you have such a line - remove it.
   - In the "Screen" section, make sure:

     - MultiGPU is Off
     - SLI is On
     - SLIMosaic is True
     - BaseMosaic is True
10. Reboot one last time. When you come back, Cinnamon should be working again and all your 3 monitors will be working again. Now you can use the NVIDIA Settings GUI to setup resolutions and screen positions/rotations, etc...