# How to get X output on two non-identical nVidia cards

Tags: xorg, drivers, nvidia, multi-monitor

I've been trying to get a second GPU (8600 GT) to be used in my system  (main GPU  is 780 Ti). The problem I'm having is that whatever I do, I can't get the monitor hooked up to the 8600 to display anything.

I've tried using nVidia-settings and editing the xorg.conf directly.  Still no progress.  I think mosaic is what I'm really after, but enabling it in the conf does nothing.  I partly suspect it's a driver issue because even though the nVidia site says the 780 and the 8600 use the same driver, the "additional driver" utility in gnome leads me to believe the 8600 is using the nouveau driver while the 780 is using the nVidia driver.

I'm wondering, does anyone know how I might go about this (without getting another 780 and hoping that works)?  The two most promising forum posts I've seen  ([this](http://www.phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?110197-Linux-multi-head-success-with-8-monitors-in-1-X-screen-without-Xinerama) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123862/how-can-I-get-xrandr-to-detect-both-nvidia-cards-2-x-gtx480-triple-head)) both deal with identical GPUs, and their solutions have not worked for me.

I know it's not a limitation of the hardware, because Windows can do it (but I *really* don't want to be using Windows).

Comment: Did you have any luck getting your setup to work?

Comment: I did not. I ended up going with AMD because they had cards that supported up to 6 monitors.